# Inconsistency between Node and Chrome in type of numeric keys in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

When I add a numeric property to a JavaScript object, I observe different behavior in Chrome than in Node.

Node converts numeric keys to strings:

```
> foo = {}
{}
> foo[123] = 'abc'
'abc'
> foo
{ '123': 'abc' }
```

Contrary to my expectations, Chrome seems to preserve the type of numeric keys:

```
> foo = {}
Object {}
> foo[123] = 'abc'
"abc"
> foo
Object {123: "abc"}
```

I want Chrome's behavior, but I'm using Node. Is there a way of preserving the type of numeric keys in Node?

Comment: It's still a _String_, it's just being displayed differently in the _Console_. `Object.keys(foo)[0]; // "123"` and `"123" in foo; // true`. `123 in foo;` is also `true` but this is because it gets cast to _String_.

Comment: If `typeof Object.keys(foo)[0] != 'string'` then the host is not compliant with ECMA-262. Note that where the property name is a valid identifier, it does not need to be quoted in an Object literal. However, if it isn't a valid identifier, it must be in quotes (i.e. Chrome *should* show `'123'`).

Comment: Just to beat a dead horse, because I see what the OP is going for: *keys in Javascript objects are always strings*.  You can't have numeric keys, regex keys, or any other type of key besides strings.  Even the keys of arrays are strings; it's just that when you dereference using a number (e.g. `foo[123]`) the number is cast to a string.

Comment: I should have used `typeof` to check the key's type. Even when I do `for (key in foo) { console.log(key) }`, integer keys are displayed without quotes. Firefox's interpreter does the same thing.

Comment: I wanted to use JavaScript objects to store set data. My solution was to store the true value as a property (the stringified value still serves as the key). There would be a problem if I wanted to include both `123` and `"123"` in the set, but it's just an exercise so I don't have to worry about that. I wonder how it would be handled in a real implementation, though.